# Application that checks a website periodically

Tags: html, vb.net

I want to make an application for personal use that checks a few items on a website every day(or every time someone runs the application) and tells me if the price has changed. What I mean is that, it should take the price tag from the source code of the website and save it then compare it to the earlier price tag. Doing this every day manually takes too much time honestly and I also want to improve my programming skills.

What should I learn and how should I go about making this application as simple as possible? You don't have to tell me everything, just point me in the right direction.

I have worked with Visual Studio(VB.Net) before and made some applications for my high school project. I also have some knowledge in C++ and HTML (enough to be able to understand the source code of a website).

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: This problem is already solved - google for it

Comment: I was unaware of that. Thank you for informing me! As for what has been done, I have tried using webclient class in VB but it has been unsuccessful so far. I can get the whole source code of the webpage but getting the price tag is very difficult for me. I don't know which way is the most effective.

Comment: if the site has a data API, it would be easier to find the information via that in a structured way. If not, then you maybe need a library which can understand and parse HTML, so you can navigate through the document to the right place. Or you could try locating the relevant text via pattern matching, using regular expressions. Plenty of information about both of those techniques are available if you google it.

Comment: Since you have the web page source, you can probably use Xpath to extract the data that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you understand html you could use a web browser control and look at the html.
In the html you can find the element with the price in the page.

> Since websites change often I do not recommend this method unless you
>   own the site or maintain you program frequently.

This is how you can retrieve the html. You will need to find the right place to look for the data.

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    MessageBox.Show(WebBrowser1.DocumentText) 
End Sub
```